# What are the chances getting enchants using level 39 in an Enchantment table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As I heard, you can find items enchanted from level 20 to 39 in the End city. I don't mean "sharpness 39" but  level 39 in an extended enchantment table.

**What are the chances I get certain enchants for the tools while enchanting to level 39**?
 Particularly the enchants I can get on a diamond sword, pickaxe, bow and book.

Comment: There is an explanation of mechanics [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchantment_mechanics). All online graphs and calculators only go up to 30, so you will have to wait until somebody will calculate probabilities or do steps explained in link yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

End-city loot enchanting differs from normal enchanting in two ways:

- max enchantment level goes up to 39,
- they can include 'treasure enchantments' like Mending and Frost Walker.

Now that MCP 9.28 for Minecraft 1.9.4 is out, I have simulated enchanting of many tools, weapons and armor on all levels 1-39 with or without including treasure enchantments. Assuming the enchantment level 20-39 is selected with equal probability, below are the enchantments you can expect to find. The full data can be downloaded from here: [Enchanting.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BycKG5bEOP-lS1JwOGJ2NGZQSkk). To play around with it, you need to download the file and use Excel (the Google Drive spreadsheet viewer won't cut it). Basic knowledge of working with pivot tables might be required.

## Diamond Sword

[image: End City enchantments for Diamond Sword]

## Diamond Pickaxe

[image: End City enchantments for Diamond Pickaxe]

## Bow

[image: End City enchantments for Bow]

## Book

[image: End City enchantments for Book]